# What happened in June/July 2011?

Tags: support, statistics

[Here are some tracking stats](http://www.quantcast.com/superuser.com) from the last year. What happened in July 2011? SO tracking looks regular, so it's at least not a network-wide glitch.

---

There's a page views peak on July 1st and 2nd.

[image]

---

On July 13th, SU lost 30% of people, visits, page views.

[image]

Comment: My guess is Google Panda hit.

Comment: Google Panda has always been my idea as well, though honestly, as long as our 'less' valuable pages stopped getting hits, you know ones with no answers for instance, then I don't think that necessarily was a bad thing